# How to make a list of shared_ptr in C++?

Tags: c++, list, shared-ptr

Let's assume i have several objects that of type MyObject, and i want to have corresponding shared_ptr's pointing to each one of them.
Then, i want to take all of those pointers and put them into a list - how would i do that?

(i'm talking about something like:

```
list<shared_ptr<MyObject>> MyList;
```

but that obviously doesn't work)

Also - is a list a growable container? or do i HAVE to declare its size when creating it?

Thanks!

Comment: [std::list::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) is one of the choices available.

Comment: Yeah, but how would i even create the list? before inserting the objects..

Comment: Why this `list<shared_ptr<MyObject>> MyList;` wouldn't work? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ddaa201e104c0a0

Comment: for some reason it gives me an error, i wrote it in my other comment below..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct MyClass{
  int a;
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> myList;
    myList.push_back(std::make_shared<MyClass>());
    myList.push_back(std::make_shared<MyClass>(3));        
}
```

Oh, and if you don't have a good reason (measure), use std::vector.

Comment: hmm for some reason i get an error "symbol shared_ptr could not be resolved", i just wanted to make sure my syntax was correct but i guess that's another problem now.. thanks!

Comment: Old compiler/ bad options? share_ptr came with C++11.